# Custom I/O manipulator in C++ for padding

Tags: c++, manipulators

In a question I found something like this:
Write a custom I/O manipulator that prints

**123.456%%%**

against the following code `cout<<setup<<123.456789;`

How can this be achieved?
I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
std::ostream& setup(std::ostream& os, double num) {
    os << std::setprecision(3) << std::fixed << std::showpoint << std::setw(10) << std::left << num << "%%%";
    return os;
}

int main() {
    //cout << setfill('?') << setw(10) << 2343.0;
    cout<<setup<<123.45678;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
1123.457

Comment: You use a lot of predefined manipulators. Have you looked at how they are implemented?

Comment: I haven't yet, actually these abstractions are quite ambiguous, could  you please explain the cause of getting 1 here extra?

Comment: `cout<<setup` is equivalent to `cout << true` and prints `1`. It's not calling the function, it's printing its address converted to `bool`. Because the signature of `setup` doesn't match that of a manipulator (see overloads (18), (19) and (20) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt))

Comment: You probably look for something [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/a9q63jzbd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @IgorTandetnik's comments above:

**The problem:**

Your `setup` function **does not match** the required signature of **I/O manipulators** as specified [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) for **`func`** - see overloads (18)-(20) of `basic_ostream& operator<<` :

```
(18): basic_ostream& operator<<(std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&) );

(19): basic_ostream& operator<<(std::basic_ios<CharT, Traits>& (*func)std::basic_ios<CharT, Traits>&) );

(20): basic_ostream& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&) );
```

Therefore when you use `cout << setup`, the `setup` function is not called (as it was done if it was a proper manipulator).
Instead the address of it is converted to `bool` and displayed as `1` (this is the initial `1` that you see).
clang even gives a meaniniful warning:

```
warning: address of function 'setup' will always evaluate to 'true'
```

**A solution:**

You can achieve what you want by using one of the I/O manipulators signatures.

Using the signature of `func` from overload (18) is shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

std::ostream& setup(std::ostream& os) {
    return os << std::setprecision(3) << std::fixed << std::showpoint << std::setw(10) << std::left << std::setfill('%');
}

int main() {
    std::cout<<setup<<123.45678;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
123.457%%%
```

**[Live demo - Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/n7jG5c6ar)**

**A side note:**  [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

---

**Update:**

If you want to truncate the value and avoid rounding, you can multiply the value by 1000 (for 3 digits precision), `floor` it, and then divide by 1000:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

std::ostream& setup(std::ostream& os) {
    return os << std::setprecision(3) << std::fixed << std::showpoint << std::setw(10) << std::left << std::setfill('%');
}

int main() {
    double val = 123.45678;
    double val_truncated = std::floor(val*1000) / 1000;
    std::cout<<setup<<val_truncated;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
123.456%%%
```

**[Live demo - Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/r36b8dsMT)**

Comment: is there anyway to get rid of that rounding up?
like 123.456%%%

Comment: [This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) is the list of standard I/O manipulators. You can have a look, I didn't see one for controlling rounding.

Comment: Added an update that shows how to avoid rounding "manually".